# applet getImage not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, applet

I am trying to do this:
http://www.javatpoint.com/Displaying-image-in-applet

However, the image will only load when I place the jpg file in the C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp

I would like to load the jpg from my java project folder but the image won't load.

I have tried doing something like "sonoo.jpg" or "/imageFolder/"sonoo.jpg"

Comment: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: The answer will depend on if the image is embedded in the project/Jar or a resource on the web server.  In any case, I strong recommend you find a new tutorial which doesn't depend on `Applet` or `JApplet` as they are now officially dead technologies